# Are all file names valid directory names?

Tags: file, directory

I need to create a directory for a file. The easiest path would be to create a directory with the same name as the file, and put the file there.

Is there any case where a valid file name would be an invalid directory name?

The directory will of course be created on the same system as where the file name is valid.

So basically I'm asking if there is any system where there are different limitations on directory names and file names.

Answer (score 0):

As the number of characters in a path is limited on some filesystems, any file that uses more than half the limit of path characters would cause problems if put into a directory of the same name.